# How to restrict Line renderer movement to a plane so that the line appears on top of the collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, renderer, leap-motion

Line renderer traces the line in 3d space using Leap motion. But I need the line to be shown as if it is drawn on top of the object.

Imagine a Simple Box  of length points A to B.
Line gets traced perfectly right from A to B. But it moves in the Z plane randomly and shows only if the line is out of the box in front view.
How to restrict that in Unity so that the line is shown as if it has been traced on top of the box.
basically the Z-plane.
Note: It is traced using Leap motion Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually override the Z value (for example to z = 0, so that its always on that plane).

Or use raycast to get actual hit point to the box collider surface (cast ray along world Z axis from the current leap finger(s) or tool position)